# Disjoint union of cosets

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $(G,\circ)$ be a group and $V,U$ subgroups with $V\leq U \leq G$. Also,
> $$G=\bigcup_n a_nU, \quad U =\bigcup_m b_mV$$
> Notice that the Unions are disjoint (I can't do \cupdot here). $aU$ and $bV$ are left [cosets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coset).
> Show that: $$G = \bigcup_{n,m} a_nb_mV.$$

---

My problem is that I don't really know what to prove here. I could just plug in the equation for $U$.

Then $$G = \bigcup_{n} a_n \bigcup_m b_mV,$$

but isn't this the same as $$G = \bigcup_{n,m} a_nb_mV\:?$$

Comment: I think you should show that an arbitrary $g \in G$ may be written as $a_n b_m v$ for some $n$, some $m$, and some $v \in V$. Perhaps this may be a little too formal, depending on the course you're doing or how comfortable you personally are with "coset arithmetic". It's definitely good to internalise what it actually means for a set to be a union of other sets. Is the union in the equality you're supposed to show also a disjoint union? In that case you have even more work to do and I think more detail is definitely merited. (PS: use `$\bigsqcup$`: $\bigsqcup$)

Comment: Yes, the two expressions are identical. Not only that, they're equal in the sense of disjoint union too, since bijections preserve disjointness and left-multiplication by a group element is bijective. (For homework purposes, that may not be the best way to submit an answer, but it is a good way to think about it I think.)

Comment: @Izaak van Dongen yes, the desired equality should also be disjoint.